# Can I hide the "Format System Memory" option on the DSi?

Tags: nintendo-dsi

On a Nintendo DSi there's an option to completely format the system memory. It's accessed from *configuration* > *format system memory* and is so easy to select that even a 3-year-old could do it (and did!)

Is there any way I can hide this option, or make the darn thing more difficult to hit? Even the confirmation is touch screen, making it very easy to use by "accident" :-(

(Ditto for Wario Ware Touched's crazy "delete all data" option that was easier for the same 3-year-old to select than it was to restart a game - I had the whole thing unlocked as well!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just received one the other day for my 4-year-old, so just learning everything, but...

You can enable Parental Controls and it appears to restrict access to a lot of functions. It will not hide the button completely, but unless your 3-year-old can figure out the 4 digit pin you choose, they won't be able to access that area.

The Parental Controls options allow you to restrict access to other things like levels of games playable, PictoChat, DS Download Play, the Browser, the Shop. I believe just by setting up parental controls, it automatically restricts access to certain system settings because they are not provided as part of the setup options.

If you missed Parental Controls in the initial setup, go to Settings, Parental Controls (Page 3) to start the setup.

Comment: Excellent. I hadn't tried this because it seemed to be all about blocking Internet and other user content. In fact, it isn't mentioned anywhere (even going through the setup) that the Parent Control will disable the "erase firmware" option, yet it works wonderfully. Thanks!